# Button connected with contenteditable paragraph

Tags: javascript

I am trying to create a paragraph with contenteditable enabled, where you will enter the value.
Later on, by pressing on the button "Submit" I want that it triggers function if, else which will take the number that the user wrote in the content editable. After checking the if-else function I want that result to be displayed in another paragraph. If the number is > 4, it should say passed, and if <, then failed. I cannot figure out, how by pressing the button trigger the function which will read my paragraph number and trigger the if function then. [It should look like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/igc8W.png)

My code

```
    <h2>Enter data</h2>
    <p><span contenteditable="true" id="iev">   </span></p>
    <button onclick="nep()">Check!</button>
    <br><br><br>
    
    <h2>Result</h2><br>
    <span contenteditable="true" id="izv"> </span>
```

and for script:

```
    var rezultats = "";
    var izv = document.getElementById("izv");
    vertejums = document.getElementById("iev");
    rezultats = parseFloat(vertejums);
    
    function nep() {
    
        if (rezultats >=4.0)
            izvads = "Passed!"
        else
            izvads = "Failed!";
    
    izv = document.getElementById("izv");
    izv.innerHTML = izvads;
    
    }
```

**Thanks!**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add textContent, and reformat code, example functional:

```js
      var rezultats = "";
      document.getElementById("poga1").onclick = function () {
        let izv = document.getElementById("izv");
        let vertejums = document.getElementById("iev");
        let rezultats = parseFloat(vertejums.textContent);
        return nep(rezultats);
      };

      function nep(rezultats) {
        console.log({ rezultats });
        if (rezultats >= 4.0) {
          izvads = "Passed!";
        } else {
          izvads = "Failed!";
        }

        izv = document.getElementById("izv");
        izv.innerHTML = izvads;
      }

      const head = document.getElementsByTagName("head");
      head[0].style.textAlign = "left";

      const main = document.getElementsByTagName("main");
      main[0].style.width = "33rem";
      main[0].style.margin = "auto";
      main[0].style.textAlign = "center";
      main[0].style.border = "solid 3px green";

      const h2 = document.getElementsByTagName("h2");
      h2[0].style.margin = "0";
      h2[0].style.padding = "1rem 0.25rem";
      h2[0].style.backgroundColor = "#f5a9d7";

      const p = document.getElementsByTagName("p");
      p[0].style.padding = "0.5rem";
      p[0].style.margin = "2.5rem";
      p[0].style.backgroundColor = "#f2e2ec";
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Parcel Sandbox</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  </head>

  <body>
    <h2>Ievadi datus</h2>
    <p>Ievade<span contenteditable="true" id="iev">5</span></p>
    <button id="poga1">Check!</button>
    <br /><br /><br />

    <h2>Rezultāts</h2>
    <br />
    <span contenteditable="true" id="izv">Vispirms ievadi datus!</span>

    <br />
    <br />
    <br />
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you really much! It worked, I will work to improve design now, and super gift to you! :)

Answer (score 0):

Holaaa.
you must pass the function in the case of clicking this button for it to be executed

```
<button onclick={nep()}>Check!</button>
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for idea. Have tried that, currently have no sucess. Didn't see any difference. Right now, for any value i enter 1 or 10, response is failied.

Comment: show me the code on playground the "CodeSandbox" ,to help you. https://codesandbox.io/s/rlkjz2n43q?file=/index.js

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/cocky-black-7mezc?file=/problem.html
Thanks!